# The first time I started tor through the terminal, it got stuck at 5%, but clicking on the tor software worked. In China

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, ubuntu

````
Sep 15 20:59:48.986 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Sep 15 20:59:48.986 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 15 20:59:48.986 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 15 20:59:48.987 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 15 20:59:49.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Sep 15 20:59:49.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Sep 15 20:59:49.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
Sep 15 20:59:50.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
^CSep 15 21:00:37.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.
gao@ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw disable
防火墙在系统启动时自动禁用
gao@ubuntu:~$ sudo tor
Sep 15 21:02:38.129 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Sep 15 21:02:38.129 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Sep 15 21:02:38.130 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Sep 15 21:02:38.131 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Sep 15 21:02:38.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Sep 15 21:02:38.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Sep 15 21:02:38.000 [warn] You are running Tor as root. You don't need to, and you probably shouldn't.
Sep 15 21:02:39.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.```

Above is the error I get when I start tor via terminal, it is stuck at 5% and does not move. 

In order to be able to connect properly, I configured the bridge in tor browser with the following configuration
![tor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OW65.jpg)
![b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yredr.jpg)
  

Thank you very much for answering my questions, it is very important to me！
````

Comment: Please note that Tor Browser comes bundled with it's own `tor` which is separate from the [little-t-tor](https://support.torproject.org/glossary/little-t-tor/) you're running on the command-line. To use bridges with little-t-tor you will have to manually edit your `torrc` (located at `/etc/tor/torrc`) and add the following lines: `UseBridges 1` `Bridge <bridge address>` Also see: https://support.torproject.org/censorship/connecting-from-china/

Comment: try with a different ISP and compare